# Sending a mail with a subject from sharepoint modern site

Tags: email, sharepoint

I am trying to set up a registration system for the courses I give at the company I work at. I have created a specific shared mailbox for this, I have a power automate flow that adds a line to a list each time I receive an email. This saves the sender as the registrant, and the subject of the mail as the course the persons registers to. I have tested this, and it works perfectly. On the sharepoint site, there is a page with a list of all the courses, with a link to the video of the course, as well as the materials. I wanted to add the mailto link to that list, next to the materials.

I thought it would be quite easy to add a button with a mailto address that contains the subject with the following format: mailto:Emailaddress?Subjectline.
Unfortunately, sharepoint doesn't seem to care about the second part of the email address and just creates an email without the subject. Thanks Microsoft, I hate it.

I have been looking online, but every solution I find gives me more problems. It seems it's possible to do this with Javascript, but js is not supported in modern sharepoint. I have been unable to change my site to classic sharepoint anywhere. I have also seen some references to creating specific new objects for sharepoint, but that was 14 years old, so I guess not really applicable anymore.
I have already spent two days searching for a solution to add a mailto link to my sharepoint page. This is the simplest part of the registration process, and it takes the longest time. This is ridiculous. Aah, The joy of working with microsoft product...

Will I have to create an power automate application for each link? Or maybe I should rethink my registration process?

Benjamin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method by using JSON codes.

1.Create a column named Attendees.

2.Column settings -> Format this column -> Advanced mode -> Use following codes.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "style": {
    "display": "=if(length([$Attendees]) > 0, 'flex', 'none')",
    "text-decoration": "none"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "href": {
      "operator": "+",
      "operands": [
        "mailto:",
        "=join([$Attendees.email], ';')",
        "?subject=",
        "emailsubject"
      ]
    }
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Mail"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": {
        "operator": "+",
        "operands": [
          "Send email to ",
          {
            "operator": "?",
            "operands": [
              "=length([$Attendees]) == 1",
              "[$Attendees.title]",
              "='all ' + length([$Attendees]) + ' members'"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]